# Swift: NSURLSession taskからJSON string を返す

Tags: swift, json, http, nsurlsession

JSON データから token を String 形式で取り出したいです。しかし以下のコードでは、`""Use of unresolved identifier "tokenString".` というエラーが生じ取り出すことが出来ません。解決策を教えてください。

```
func authentication() -> String {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://~~~/v2/authenticate/api")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var loginID = "my_ID"
    var apiKey = "my_APIKEY"
    var postString:NSString = "login_id=\(loginID)&api_key=\(apiKey)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")


        let json = JSON(data:data)
        if let token = json["auth_token"].stringValue{
            println("\(token)")

            tokenString = self.didReceiveAuthToken(token)///Edited 
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return tokenString
}
func didReceiveAuthToken(token : String) ->String{
    return token
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のようにすることで解決致しました。

```
var tokenString : String = ""  
func authentication(){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://~~~/v2/authenticate/api")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var loginID = "my_ID"
    var apiKey = "my_KEY"
    var postString:NSString = "login_id=\(loginID)&api_key=\(apiKey)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")


        let json = JSON(data:data)
        if let token = json["auth_token"].stringValue{
            println("\(token)")
            self.didReceiveAuthToken(token)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}

func didReceiveAuthToken(token : String){
    tokenString = token
}
```

Comment: 質問の内容が無事解決した場合は、ご自身の回答にチェックを付けると、後から見た方にもわかりやすいかと思いますよ。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
しかしながら、自分の回答には48時間経たないとチェックを付けられないようです。時間が経ち次第チェック致します。